# PrestaShop install fails with exception 'Property Currency->decimals is not valid'

Tags: php, installation, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I can't install PrestaShop 1.6.1.18 (or 1.6.1.17 either) recently.

I get this error in the last installation step :

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PrestaShopException' with message 'Property Currency->decimals is not valid' in */classes/ObjectModel.php:917
```

I am pretty sure it did work before, and I dont think I changed anything in my configuration.

PrestaShop version 1.6.1.x
PHP version 5.6

Comment: OK so what's the value of `Property Currency->decimals`... ?

Comment: `Property Currency->decimals` value is `2`, and it tries to validate it as a boolean, that may be the cause... but I dont understand why it worked before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same issue for me. I solved it with this post : https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/743719-php-fatal-error-property-currency-decimals-is-not-valid/ :

> I don't know which localization are you trying to install, i was
>   installing the Italian pack. I think that Prestashop made some change
>   to its localization files (in a wrong way), because if you go to
>   http://api.prestashop.com/localization/16/it.xml (it's the file that
>   presta try to import during the installation process), you can see
>   that 'decimals' field is set to 2, that causes the error.
>
> However after the first installation attempt, prestashop should copy
>   this file in cache in order to use it next times, so try to go to
>   /cache/sandbox/ and see if there is a file named
>   16{your_localization_iso}.xml and, if it exists, modify the currency
>   line changing decimals form 2 to 1. It should fix the problem.

So, it seems a temporary trouble with the language packs download from Prestashop during the installation.

Merci !